# C - GLFW window doesn't open on Debian

Tags: c, opengl, debian

I'm trying to get started with GLFW on Debian, I've tried compiling and running an example program but it refuses to run. With the help of a couple of printf statements I've found that when the program tries to open a GLFW window it fails, then exits - but I don't know why. Any help would be amazing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>    // For malloc() etc.
#include <stdio.h>     // For printf(), fopen() etc.
#include <math.h>      // For sin(), cos() etc.
#include <GL/glfw.h>   // For GLFW, OpenGL and GLU


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Draw() - Main OpenGL drawing function that is called each frame
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void Draw( void )
{
    int    width, height;  // Window dimensions
    double t;              // Time (in seconds)
    int    k;              // Loop counter

    // Get current time
    t = glfwGetTime();

    // Get window size
    glfwGetWindowSize( &width, &height );

    // Make sure that height is non-zero to avoid division by zero
    height = height < 1 ? 1 : height;

    // Set viewport
    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

    // Clear color and depht buffers
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Set up projection matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );    // Select projection matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                 // Start with an identity matrix
    gluPerspective(                   // Set perspective view
        65.0,                         // Field of view = 65 degrees
        (double)width/(double)height, // Window aspect (assumes square pixels)
        1.0,                          // Near Z clipping plane
        100.0                         // Far Z clippling plane
    );

    // Set up modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );     // Select modelview matrix
    glLoadIdentity();                 // Start with an identity matrix
    gluLookAt(                        // Set camera position and orientation
        0.0, 0.0, 10.0,               // Camera position (x,y,z)
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,                // View point (x,y,z)
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0                 // Up-vector (x,y,z)
    );


// **** Draw a circle of points ***

// Save the current modelview matrix on the stack
glPushMatrix();

// Translate (move) the points to the upper left of the display
glTranslatef( -4.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f );

// Rotate the points about the z-axis and the x-axis
glRotatef( 35.0f * (float)t, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glRotatef( 60.0f * (float)t, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

// Now draw the points - we use a for-loop to build a circle
glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glBegin( GL_POINTS );
for( k = 0; k < 20; k ++ )
{
    glVertex3f( 2.0f * (float)cos( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                2.0f * (float)sin( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                0.0f );
}
glEnd();

// Restore modelview matrix
glPopMatrix();


// **** Draw a circle of lines ***

// Save the current modelview matrix on the stack
glPushMatrix();

// Translate (move) the lines to the upper right of the display
glTranslatef( 4.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f );

// Rotate the points about the z-axis and the x-axis
glRotatef( 45.0f * (float)t, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glRotatef( 55.0f * (float)t, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

// Now draw the lines - we use a for-loop to build a circle
glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
for( k = 0; k < 20; k ++ )
{
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.05f * (float)k, 0.0f );
    glVertex3f( 2.0f * (float)cos( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                2.0f * (float)sin( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                0.0f );
}
glEnd();

// Restore modelview matrix
glPopMatrix();


// **** Draw a disc using trinagles ***

// Save the current modelview matrix on the stack
glPushMatrix();

// Translate (move) the triangles to the lower left of the display
glTranslatef( -4.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f );

// Rotate the triangles about the z-axis and the x-axis
glRotatef( 25.0f * (float)t, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glRotatef( 75.0f * (float)t, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

// Now draw the triangles - we use a for-loop to build a disc
// Since we are building a triangle fan, we also specify a first
// vertex for the centre point of the disc.
glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN );
glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f );
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
for( k = 0; k < 21; k ++ )
{
    glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.05f * (float)k, 1.0f );
    glVertex3f( 2.0f * (float)cos( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                2.0f * (float)sin( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                0.0f );
}
glEnd();

// Restore modelview matrix
glPopMatrix();


// **** Draw a disc using a polygon ***

// Save the current modelview matrix on the stack
glPushMatrix();

// Translate (move) the polygon to the lower right of the display
glTranslatef( 4.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f );

// Rotate the polygon about the z-axis and the x-axis
glRotatef( 65.0f * (float)t, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glRotatef( -35.0f * (float)t, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

// Now draw the polygon - we use a for-loop to build a disc
glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
for( k = 0; k < 20; k ++ )
{
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.05f * (float)k );
    glVertex3f( 2.0f * (float)cos( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                2.0f * (float)sin( 0.31416 * (double)k ),
                0.0f );
}
glEnd();

// Restore modelview matrix
glPopMatrix();


// **** Draw a single quad ***

// Save the current modelview matrix on the stack
glPushMatrix();

// Rotate the quad about the y-axis
glRotatef( 60.0f * (float)t, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

// Now draw the quad
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glVertex3f( -1.5f, -1.5f, 0.0f );
glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
glVertex3f(  1.5f, -1.5f, 0.0f );
glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glVertex3f(  1.5f,  1.5f, 0.0f );
glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glVertex3f( -1.5f,  1.5f, 0.0f );
glEnd();

// Restore modelview matrix
glPopMatrix();
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// main() - Program entry point
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
int    ok;             // Flag telling if the window was opened
int    running;        // Flag telling if the program is running

// Initialize GLFW
glfwInit();
// Open window
ok = glfwOpenWindow(
    100, 100,          // Width and height of window
    8, 8, 8,           // Number of red, green, and blue bits for color buffer
    8,                 // Number of bits for alpha buffer
    24,                // Number of bits for depth buffer (Z-buffer)
    0,                 // Number of bits for stencil buffer
    GLFW_WINDOW        // We want a desktop window (could be GLFW_FULLSCREEN)
);

        printf("here");
// If we could not open a window, exit now
if( !ok )
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
printf("not here");


// Set window title
glfwSetWindowTitle( "My OpenGL program" );

// Enable sticky keys
glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

// Main rendering loop
do
{
    // Call our rendering function
    Draw();

    // Swap front and back buffers (we use a double buffered display)
    glfwSwapBuffers();

    // Check if the escape key was pressed, or if the window was closed
    running = !glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) &&
              glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED );
}
while( running );

// Terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

// Exit program
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to comment on self-explanatory lines.

Answer (score 1):

You're sure it's glfwOpenWindow that's failing? I don't know why that might be, perhaps you're using too many bits for your z-buffer? That's the only thing I can think of.

Try this

```
GLFWvidmode dvm;
glfwGetDesktopMode(&dvm);
glfwOpenWindow(winWidth, winHeight, dvm.RedBits, dvm.GreenBits, dvm.BlueBits, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);
```

And see if it still fails.

Comment: GLFW matches the requested pixel format to those available on the system and doesn't require an exact match for any channel bit depth, so this cannot cause `glfwOpenWindow` to fail.