# GLFW window fails to open (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, opengl, ubuntu, glfw

When compiling and running my GLFW-based C program under Ubuntu (9.04), it fails when trying to open the window (it compiles fine, having installed the latest GLFW). I've tried varying resolutions, going as low as 300x300, and left the bit depths to zeros, hoping a default will catch on.

The relevant piece of code reads (directly snipped from the top of my main file, based on the example file `gears.c`):

```
// File: main.c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

#ifndef PI
#define PI 3.141592654
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialize GLFW:
    glfwInit();

    if (!glfwOpenWindow(300, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW)) // Yo failure!
    {
        printf("Window open failed.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle("...");

    ...

    // Clean up:
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Other noteworthy facts are:

- Running Ubuntu inside VirtualBox 3.0.2, config'd w/ 512 MB RAM, 3D acceleration enabled, 64 MB VRAM, Guest Additions successfully installed
- `glxgears` works fine, even > 300 FPS
- built GLFW using `make-x11`
- makefile command line:

  `` gcc `pkg-config --cflags libglfw` main.c -o program `pkg-config --libs libglfw` -lglfw -lGLU -lGL -lm ``
- Mark's tip on [C - GLFW window doesn't open on Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746000/c-glfw-window-doesnt-open-on-debian) does not seem to alleviate the situation

Edit:

Are there any way to extract a more fancy error message? Any `getLastErrorDesc()` or debug log files?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the version packaged in Ubuntu or some version from the GLFW Subversion repository?  The GLXFBConfig selection in the Subversion repo was broken for quite a while, due to the removal of the custom Visual selection, so you may have received bad code.

If that's the case, you should either revert to the version bundled with Ubuntu or pull a fresh tree from Subversion.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to post a suggestion. I downloaded it from http://glfw.sourceforge.net/download.html, being oblivious to Ubuntu already having packages for it (albeit uninstalled at the time). Currently I have solved the problem with a "physical" installation of Ubuntu. I will, however, and try to remove the stuff that the GLFW install script copied onto the virtual hard drive, and use Ubuntu's built in package support for GLFW, to see if that works.

Comment: I think what you downloaded from the site is identical to the package in Ubuntu, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I've been suffering from the same problem.

At last I figured out how to solve this one.
I was using "make x11-install" to install the library.

The procedure would be as following:

1. run "make x11-clean" (not necessary)
2. use vim or whatever editor to edit Makefile.x11.in in glfw/lib/x11 folder (and Makefile.x11 if you don't run process 1), change the PREFIX from "/usr/local" to "/user"
3. run "make x11-dist-install" for installation

I haven't tried if its "dist-install" that matters or the location, but it works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a window with 0bpp, of course it's going to fail :)

Try this:

```
    glfwOpenWindow(
                   800, 600,   // Window size
                   8, 8, 8, 8, // bitdepth per channel (RGBA)
                   24,         // Z buffer bitdepth
                   0,          // Aux buffer bitdepth
                   GLFW_WINDOW // Window
                  );
```

Also, on latest Ubuntu, there's actually a package called libglfw-dev you can install, just in case you forgot to link any extra libraries (like librandr).

Comment: Have you checked the documentation to back up your facts on the bit depth? Because it clearly states that 0 => default depth. I used 8 bits per channel initially, then switched to 0 to see if GLFW could determine a better setting. I'll look into libglfw-dev and librandr, though.

Comment: That's weird, I was sure 0 was an invalid value. I'll leave it here for your comment to make sense. You are indeed right.

Comment: I've tried 16-bits (5, 6, 5) and other combinations. I'm thinking it might be an issue with the virtualization, so I'll take a look at Mesa.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with GLFW 2.7.7, pulled as a .tar.bz2 directly from the GLFW website. `glfwOpenWindow` always returned false, even with no hints and no bit depths specified.

I was building libglfw myself, and loading it from the working directory using the rpath link flag. I did not have the Ubuntu libglfw installed.

Using the Ubuntu repository version (`sudo apt-get install libglfw-dev`), the window opens as expected.

One of the significant differences between the two library versions is the result of calling glfwGetVideoModes. On the broken GLFW 2.7.7, this returned only the desktop resolution and depth. On the working version, Ubuntu package 2.7.2-1, this returned the expected variety of modes.